# Do external (editor-independent) refactoring tools exist?

Tags: refactoring

Does a refactoring (able do conscious language-aware rename classes/variables renaming and replace simple constructions instead of doing dumb string search-and-replace) tool exist which can be used without IDE/editor?

I am particularly interested in Scala, C# and PHP languages.

Answer (score 1):

For Scala there is a refactoring library that can be used standalone: http://scala-refactoring.org/

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you are looking for, but [Bicycle Repair Man](http://bicyclerepair.sourceforge.net/), a Python refactoring tool, ships as an editor-agnostic refactoring library.  It's actually used via editor/IDE plugins though.